# Package R error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

So I really need your help guys! I recently started learning android and on my first app try the Android studio shows some error saying "Package R is not loaded" or "Package R not found" 
My code is 100% right and I even started entire project from scratch twice.
Can you please help Me out?

Comment: Clean and rebuild did not help?

Comment: Errors in R could be as simple as a String error or linking to an Id that doesn't exist. Can you show us the exact errors you're getting?

Comment: import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
    display(1);
       private void display(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);}}

Comment: so this is my code

Answer (score 1):

Clean your code with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: import android.os.Bundle; import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.view.View; import android.widget.TextView; public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); public void submitOrder(View view) { display(1); private void display(int number) { TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view); quantityTextView.setText("" + number);}